# Editing a vector layer with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

i am trying to develop a webmapping application using openlayers, geoserver, JSF javascript. I published my postgis layers on geoserver and added them to a google basemap on a xhtml page using a javascript code. Now i want to edit one of the layers i published. on the script i added the folowing code :

```
function  drawpoint(){
          //nouveau_risque = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("nouveau risque");
           map.addLayer(nouveau_risque);
           drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(nouveau_risque, OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
          map.addControl(drawControl);
          drawControl.activate();
         // drawControl.events.register('featureadded', drawControl, onFeatureAdded);
          drawControl.events.register('featureadded', drawControl, function(f) {

                // create a WKT reader/parser/writer          
                var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();

                 // write out the feature's geometry in WKT format
                 var out = wkt.write(f.feature);
                 console.log(out);
               });
            // drawControl.deactivate();


           }

           function endDraw(){
               drawControl.deactivate();
           }
```

and on the xhtml page i wrote :

```
                    <div> 
            <input type="button" value="add point" onclick="drawpoint()"> </input>
            <input type="button" value="stop editing" onclick="EndDraw()"> </input>
                   </div>
                   <div  style="width:100px; height:60px"> <script type="test/javascript">document.writeln(out);</script></div>
```

so that i can get the geom value of the added point so that i can add it to the database.

The problem is when i run the page, the add control is displayed and i can add a pointy however i don't get the feature's geometry in WKT.

Than you all for your help